# Heroku - unable to install package from github

Tags: node.js, heroku

Trying to deploy my app but Heroku is unable to access the package "express-flash"

[image]

Looks like heroku can't load the package with npm if the package is stored in GIThub ?

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Using npm install
If you’d rather use npm install instead of npm ci to create the build environment, you can use the USE_NPM_INSTALL environment variable to let the buildpack know. You can do this by running:

```
heroku config:set USE_NPM_INSTALL=true
```

then deploy and voila!